# Can I use BERT or BART for machine translation?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-translation

I am working on a project to use a pre-trained model and finetune it for customized language translations, for example from English to French. Is it possible to load these models in Tensorflow and run them to see how translations turn out and fine-tune afterward?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the fastest way to do so is relying on the HuggingFace transformers library. If you're not familiar with it, you may take a look at their official [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/quicktour.html). To fine-tune a BART for NMT you can use directly this provided [script](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/seq2seq/run_translation.py) (it works with some other pre-trained models too).